# Grunt run task now ( as opposed to queueing )

Tags: gruntjs

> Enqueue one or more tasks. Every specified task in taskList will be
>   run immediately after the current task completes, in the order
>   specified. The task list can be an array of tasks or individual task
>   arguments.

```
grunt.task.run(taskList)
```

By adding `grunt.task.run()` I can add it in the queue. **Is it possible to run the task synchronously** ( wait for it to complete before continuing ) ?

Note: I'm not sure if it's possible with `grunt.event`, but *`grunt.event` is asynchronous* anyway, not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `grunt.tasks(tasklist)` instead

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there are several ways you might accomplish this, depending upon your requirements.  The docs on [creating tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) have some sample code that might help like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" task.', function() {
  // Enqueue "bar" and "baz" tasks, to run after "foo" finishes, in-order.
  grunt.task.run('bar', 'baz');
  // Or:
  grunt.task.run(['bar', 'baz']);
});
```

That's the simplest example provided in the docs and others show how to check for success that another task has run without errors, work with config data, etc...